# open in new tab using right click not working angularjs using ng-repeat, ng-href and ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-href

this is my code..

```
 <div class="container-fluid" id="con2">
      <div class="row-fluid" id="row2">
            <div  ng-repeat="product in productDetails" class="row">
              <div id="searchDiv1" class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2 padding-0" id="div21" >
                <div class="Enlarge">
                  <img style="width:70px; height:70px;"  class="center-block enlarge pull-right {{product.classInfo}}" ng-model="productImage" ng-src="{{product.documents.image}}">
                  <span>  <img id="dataImage"  ng-src="{{product.documents.image}}"></span>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-xs-6 {{product.classInfo}}" id="div23">
                <div id="p2" class="ng-binding "><a href="#" ng-click="openProductSheet(product.id)" >{{product.id}}</a></div>
                <div id="p3" class="ng-binding" > {{product.descriptionTranslation}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

The problem is that the same page is getting loading instead of link in new tab]
I saw some of the blogs of stackoverflow but not able to fix the problem.what is the mistake i am doing ?? any help is appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is on line  <div id="p2" class="ng-binding "><a href="#" ng-click="openProductSheet(product.id)" >{{product.id}}</a></div>

Comment: you need to use anchor so that it will give option to open it in new tab

Comment: its there a href="#".

Comment: What is inside openproductsheet?

Comment: i am just redirecting based in productid . $window.open(url/path)

Comment: @schneider so it should be `$window.open('url/path', '_blank') ` so that it will redirect to new tab

Comment: @schneider, you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682995/angularjs-open-link-in-new-tab-when-conditionally-routing-via-controller/23334508#23334508. It's not exact as per your requirement but might help you.

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: Can you post your openProductSheet function? I have created a plunker which works just fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/41B9O0Dqhzo6K2FHYjZi?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the link by adding a target attribute:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" ng-click="openProductSheet(product.id)" >{{product.id}}</a>
```